# Call controller method from different thread in iOS

Tags: ios, multithreading, controller, dispatch-async

I'm trying to call this method from a music-rendering function that is run in a different thread. The method is inside `InstrumentGridViewController`.

```
- (IBAction)stopPlayback:(id)sender{
    [self stopToneUnit];
}
```

This is how I'm calling the method:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ [InstrumentGridViewController stopPlayback: nil]; } );
```

But I'm getting this warning:

```
Class method `+stopPlayback` not found (return type defaults to `id`)
```

And when I try to run:

```
erminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[InstrumentGridViewController stopPlayback:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x13e50'
```

I'm sure the method is there so I really don't see why this is happening.

**EDIT: H2CO3 said I should call the stopPlayback method on the currently running instance. Any ideas how I could do that?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the method is implemented as an instance method and not as a class method. You must call it on an **object** of class InstrumentGridViewController, and **not on the class itself.**

Comment: Is there any way to get the currently running instance of the controller? It seems weird to create a new instance of my entire controller.

Comment: @Sled you're quite right about that! I think you should grab  reference to it using an instance variable of the class from which you make that dispatch_async call.

Comment: Sounds like a perfect candidate to implementing a protocol / delegate pattern.

Comment: How would that go Rog? Something like a member that is a reference or pointer to my controller? I had a look at the delegate pattern but it's not very clear how it could help me.